# What are the maximum number of duplicates for a given key in a B+-tree

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, theory, b-tree

Given a B+-tree with a branching factor of g and s being the number of keys contained, what would be the maximum number of duplicates allowed for a single key lets call this s<sub>i</sub>? And how do we calculate that number?

My first idea was to say that each level can have have one instance of s<sub>i</sub>, so my idea would be to maximise the depth, which would be our answer, however I'm not sure about this.

I have searched online but it seems no one has asked this question before, first time asking a question here so any feedback is welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A b-tree which allows duplicate keys shouldn't have any intrinsic limit on the number of duplicates. If there is a limit, then that's specific to the implementation.

Comment: @boneill, no I mean if we where to fit as many as possible inside the tree. The limitations are a part of the tree itself, no duplicates in the samen node and respecting the order (a left child is smaller of equal to the parent's node relevant key.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer to your question because it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

A proper [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) cannot contain duplicate 'keys' because the values in question would not uniquely identify their associated data and hence they would not be keys.

The reason is that B-trees do not distinguish between nodes for routing searches (internal nodes) and nodes for storing data (leaf nodes) as some other data structures do. All nodes in a classic B-tree are data-bearing, and the internal nodes just happen to also route search traffic.

[B+ trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), on the other hand, store **all** data in leaf nodes and use the nodes above the leaf level (a.k.a. 'index layer') only for routing. The values in internal nodes - a.k.a. 'separator keys' - only have to guide searches but they do not have to uniquely identify any data records. They do not even have to correspond to any actually existing key values (i.e. ones that have associated data). That makes it often possible to shorten the separator keys drastically, as long as they keep separating the same things. For example, "F" is just as effective at separting "Arthur Dent" from "Zaphod Beeblebrox" as "Ford Prefect" is.

One consequence is that one and the same value could potentially occur at each and every level of the B+ tree without any ill effect, since only the one and only occurrence at the leaf level actually works as a data key; the ones in internal nodes serve only to guide searches.

Another consequence is that internal nodes in B+ trees can usually hold orders of magnitude more keys than internal nodes in B-trees (which are diluted by record data and do not allow shortening of key values). This increases I/O and cache efficiency, and it usually makes B+ trees more shallow than B-trees containing the same data.

As for calculating the height: outside of homework assignments you actually need *two* node capacity values to describe a B+ tree, one for the maximum number of separator keys in an internal node and one for the maximum number of keys (data records) in a leaf node. Basically, you divide the number of records by the leaf node capacity to determine the number of 'outputs' that the index layer needs to have, and then feed that into the usual [B-tree height formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Best_case_and_worst_case_heights) in order to determine the height of the index layer.